# Linear model coefficient negative in summary but positive in plot

Tags: r

I am an R beginner, so sorry if I missing something basic. I did a linear fit with 2 input variables and 1 output. Plots of the output vs each input show a clear positive slope for each. However, the data output shows a negative coefficient for one variable. Can someone help me understand why the plots appear to show positive correlation slope for myoutput vs d3 while the model shows a negative coefficient? Thanks!

*Input variables*: d2, d3

*Output variable*: myoutput

```
> mydata = read.table("tdata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> lm.fit= lm(myoutput ~ d2 + d3, data = mydata)
> summary(lm.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = myoutput ~ d2 + d3, data = mydata)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.011531 -0.001770  0.000019  0.001800  0.008234 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -7.601e-06  1.335e-04  -0.057    0.955    
d2           1.329e+00  5.776e-02  23.012   <2e-16 ***
d3          -4.931e-01  5.197e-02  -9.488   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.00293 on 486 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8265,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8258 
F-statistic:  1158 on 2 and 486 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

[image: myoutput vs. d2]

[image: myoutput vs. d3]

Comment: This is a statistics question, not programming... Your plots show the bivariate relations between `myoutput` and `d2` / `d3`. The fitted model on the other hand contains the effects of `d2` and `d3` when the other variable is being controlled for (held constant or "partialled out"). The coefficient of `d3` states that two units with identical values on `d2` who differ on `d3` by 1 are expected to differ in `myoutput` by approximately -0.5. It doesn't mean that the "overall" effect of `d3` (when not controlling for `d2`) can't still be positive.

Comment: if you run reg just between myoutput and d3 (without d2), then that should be positive; that is what your second plot is saying,

Answer (score 5):

I'm 95% certain that what is going on here is that d2 and d3 are highly correlated. Examine your data to check this.

The important thing to think about is that in this scatterplot, you are examine the relation between d2 or d3 and myoutput *without* considering the other covariate. Thus, individually, d2 and d3 may be highly correlated with myoutput. But this is not considering the full relation between d2, d3 and myoutput.

Consider this model, for example:

$x_{i1} \sim N(0,1)$

$x_{i2} \sim N(0,0.1) + x_{1i}$  ($x_{2i}$ highly correlated with $x_{1i}$)

$y_i \sim x_{1i} - \frac{x_{2i}}{2} + N(0,1)$ (Greater positive effect of $x_{1i}$, lesser negative effect of $x_{2i}$)

In this case, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are very highly correlated. Thus, the two individual relations between ($x_1$, $y$) and ($x_2$, $y$) will look nearly identical (i.e. positively correlated). However, fitting the full model will reveal that after adjusting for $x_{1i}$, there is a *negative* effect of $x_{2i}$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Yes, colinear/correlated inputs is the problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Cliff_AB How is it possible that the two variables are highly correlated and still statistically significant? Shouldn't the standard errors be large if indeed it was a problem of high collinearity, as you are suggesting? I am just wondering.

Comment: Having highly correlated predictors means that the results will have higher standard errors than if the predictors were uncorrelated (all else remaining the same). It doesn't force it to be insignificant though. Looking at the summary results, we see that the residual standard error is 0.00293. So even though d2 and d3 are highly correlated, the error term is very small with a good sized dataset (n = 489).